# Proposal deleted from Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

I created a proposal for a Hindi Q&A forum at Area 51 (the name was Jigyasa) and it had almost 60 followers and it was moving to the commitment phase. Today I logged in to Area 51 after a gap of about a month and saw that the proposal was deleted. (Earlier search for "Hindi" would show up my proposal in results, now it doesn't.) I never received any email notification about it. What happened to it?

Answer (score 7):

Under your profile, you had a proposal called "Indic Q&A | जिज्ञासा" (I see no entry for either "Jigyasa" nor "Hindi").

That proposal had not received a question or follower since the middle of August and was removed as part of the regular maintenance of Area 51.

> #### This proposal has been deleted.
>
> Inactive proposals that do not receive any activity for one month are subject to deletion. Occasionally, proposals may be removed from Area 51 for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etc. For more information, see the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Hi Robert, IMO this is quite rude. Its very difficult to bring collect people and create a community in niche areas like Indic Computing (it took me 6 years to being a mailing list to to the level of 500 members), these things don't happen overnight. I think you guys are doing it in excess and this would just demotivate smaller communities. I don't think I have the courage to start all over again. Sad really!

Comment: @Dee: Most people feel just the opposite; that I let proposals linger *way* too long before removal. Even *you* stopped contributing to the proposal. The proposal showed *absolutely* no sign of support for over 4 months: not *one* question, no comments, no additional followers. Not one. That's all it takes to keep a proposal alive, just a little bit of support on the rare occasion. If you ever feel that you are able to gain more interest, you are welcome to resubmit your proposal.

Comment: Robert, is it really too much to expect from a sophisticated software and experienced moderators that they will at least send one if not a few email alerts to the proposer before his and other's hard-work is dumped in to trash-box? I received no emails over these "4 months" from area51, for people who have a full-time day job will not be able to monitor stuff on a daily basis, after all this is just a hobby, we are not going to earn a living out of this. Anyways...