# What counts as 'activity' regarding Area51 proposed sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

It's said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75107/proposal-deleted-from-area-51/75351#75351) that if a proposal hasn't seen activity for a month, it will be closed automatically. What counts as *activity*? Is it votes, comments, followers, or just new questions?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74229/latest-activity-at-area-51-could-be-wrongly-calculated/74245#74245

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "latest activity" field displayed on the proposal shows the last time the proposal itself changed. That includes:

- Edits to the title or  description
- New example questions

But the FAQ describes that proposals can be deleted after a month of *absolutely no* activity at all. That includes *any* type of activity:

- Edits to the title or description
- New or edited example questions
- New comments
- New followers or committers
- Votes on questions